# How to change upload path when use formidable with express in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, formidable

Actually I come across two problem

**First, how to change the upload path**

my folder structure is like this:

```
|__app.js
|__upload
```

my node code is in app.js and boot from it, 
so I want to the upload image upload to the upload folder, I change the path:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm;
form.uploadDir = "./upload";
```

It seems it upload successed, but I don't know where the file go, 
it doesn't in the upload folder.

So what the correct path name?

**The second problem is**

If I don't change it, it could upload correctly to the `C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp`
but it will be renamed without the foramt,

so how can I get the upload format and renamed by myself?

**The third problem is**

I also bind handler to the `process` event,
like

```
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    console.log(bytesReceived + ' ' + bytesExpected);
});
```

but it seems doesn't work,when upload log nothing. why?Do I missing something?

Here is my all code:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm;
    // form.uploadDir = "./upload";
    console.log(form.uploadDir);

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
      if (err) return res.end('You found error');
      console.log(files.image);
    });

    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        console.log(bytesReceived + ' ' + bytesExpected);
    });

    form.on('error', function(err) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('error:\n\n'+util.inspect(err));
    });

    // res.end('Done');
    res.send("well done");

    return;
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you have to tell your app that you don't want the `bodyParser` to handle file uploads.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

is [equivalent](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) to

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
```

Remove the last line to deal with file uploads yourself. Add some custom options when initializing your form

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ 
  uploadDir: __dirname + '/tmp',  // don't forget the __dirname here
  keepExtensions: true
});
```

Now your code should work.