# How can I access the uploadDir attribute of Express?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable, node.js-connect

In an Express app.js I define **uploadDir = "./tmp"**, but how can I access it later?

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));

  app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./tmp', keepExtensions: true})); // <--

  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

Comment: Use the file system methods to access the file... like fs.read etc.

Comment: which file do you mean? I mean here the config variable uploadDir, which is originally from node-formidable (connect uses formidable and express uses connect, so this variable is used indirectly by express too), but I do not know, how access it from express. From formidable it would be with IncomingForm.uploadDir possibly

Comment: If the form for upload is like this... <input type="file" name="avatar">' then it can be accessed as var tmp_path = req.files.avatar.path;

Comment: but, it is only possible when I get an upload, and what is before? I would like to get it from express, smth. like: express.uploadDir or app.get('uploadDir')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to middleware like `bodyParser` go straight through to the middleware. All of the Express middleware is provided by Connect, so it doesn't even know anything about Express. The `uploadDir` is captured in the `multipart` closure of the [multipart middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js). It is stored via the closure, and never stored anywhere else, or passed to Express, so the only way to access the original value is to access it as part of the `options` object initially passed in. There is no other way.

If you want that value to be accessible by reading from `app`(as you said in your comment), then you should set it on there yourself separately. That said, this method is a bit ugly and means that you have to set the value twice.

```
app.set('uploadDir', './tmp');
```

Comment: does it mean, that then I do not even need to set 'uploadDir' via the middleware: `app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./tmp', keepExtensions: true}));`? so the `app.set('uploadDir', './tmp');` does it already or is it then just an attribute I set to the app?

Comment: @static No you still need to pass it to `bodyParser` too. The middleware has no knowledge of the app and the app has no knowlege of the middleware (usually).

Comment: hm, not really what I want. So if I will change the uploadDir - I need to do it twice, or I need write a method wrapping for setting it twice.

Comment: If you wanted to change the value, why didn't you put that in the question! This is an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Since this question has been answered as you asked it initially, please ask a new question explaining what you actually want to do.

Comment: 1. the attribute `uploadDir` goes not to the connect but to the formidable module
2. no link/prove to the "there is no other way", or did I interpreted it wron?
3. `app.set('uploadDir', './tmp')` and `app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./tmp', keepExtensions: true}))`: the first `uploadDir` and the second one they have nothing in common, except the name, so you just provided a bad smell solution (I thought the people here are more professional)

Comment: And, no, this is not the XY problem - this is your logical fallacy, thinking your interpretation and your answer is the single point of truth: I asked: how can I **access the attribute**, but not, how can I write the **value of this attribute** down somewhere else for my purpose and access than later even if the original `uploadDir` already changed many times (yes, not so real case, but still possible). Sorry if it sounds not so nice from me to writing it, but I don't like if someone try to press

Comment: @static Sorry if I sounded annoyed. Yes, it goes to Formidable via Connect, but never touches Express, which was my point. I didn't provide a link to anything because I thought my explanation was enough. I'll expand on it. I'm confused though, do you want to change the uploadDir, or just access it? In your second comment you said `So if I will change the uploadDir - I need to do it twice`, but in the question you only mentioned accessing.

Comment: @static I set it on app because that was exactly the example you gave in your comment on the question: `I would like to get it from express, smth. like: express.uploadDir or app.get('uploadDir')` You are correct though, it isn't an nice way to do it.

Comment: no problem, maybe my comment was really confusing too, but the meaning of the **access** was **to handle this attribute in the future** (e.g. to read the original `uploadDir`, not just my copy of it: it could work for just one time, but if I forget to update it - the concept will fail). I found now here (SO-question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022353/how-to-change-upload-path-when-use-formidable-with-express-in-node-js] that there are 2 possibilities to handle uploads: by `express` or by `formidable`. I will try to investigate it. If I find the direct access, I will post it here.